# How do I create an HTML Email (Not Text) Verification Template in Parse

Tags: parse-platform, html-email

I see where to edit the Email verification template in Parse, but if I add HTML to the field it is still sent as a text email (Not HTML as I would like) and therefore it is not displayed properly on the client end.  Does anyone know how/if I can create HTML emails for the verification template in Parse? The documentation states HTML can be used for Pro accounts, but there are no more pro accounts... So this doesn't make sense and I don't see how to do it.  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Maybe the documentation means a paid account?

Comment: I have given my credit card, but we are still in development so increasing the limits makes no sense at this point.  I would assume giving Parse my credit card would constitute a paid account but still no luck.  Any other ideas or has anyone setup the verification email to use HTML?

Comment: Facing the same issue. I searched around and the only thing I found is to use an additional service: Maybe using Parse Cloud Code with the Module 'Mandrill' (it's an email service by MailChimp) could solve this. Here's a lead: https://www.parse.com/questions/sending-email-with-mandrill-on-ios

Answer (score 0):

VERY uncool of Parse but - since 2012 - only the Paid accounts have access to customize the Email Verification templates... **:(**

[Express Your Brand With Parse](http://blog.parse.com/learn/engineering/express-your-brand-with-parse/)